# Add multiple suggestion values in select ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
<%= f.select :id, lists.collect{ |p| [p.name, p.id] } << "add product", { prompt: t("select product") }, { :class => "selectpicker" } %>
```

The problem is that "add product" is being added on the last index but I want it on the second index.

Comment: try `insert(1, "add product")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use insert and pass the index you want to insert the data in:

Tweaking a bit the code:

```
<%= f.select :id, lists.map { |p| [p.name, p.id] }.insert(1, 'add product'), { prompt: t('select product') }, { class: 'selectpicker' } %>
```